# Quartus II: how to search for a sub-function in the whole project (multiple vhd files)

Tags: vhdl, quartus

If I want to search for e.g. a sub-function to see where it's implemented or where the sub-function being used in the whole project (multiple vhd files), then how can I do it in Quartus II software?

For example: in Eclipse I can 
    - "**Ctrl** + **Left_Click**" or
    - Right_click on the sub-function name and choose search in project etc.

Thanks

Comment: A function is made visible through a use clause. So check what packages are used in your design unit and open the file containing that package.

Comment: Hi Paebbels, thanks for your reply. Yes, I guess I can check where the sub-function is implemented. But let say if I have a big project with multiple .vhd files and the sub-function are called at several places among these .vhd files. Then is there a search option in Quartus, which shows every single place where the sub-function being called. 
Like for e.g. as in Eclipse.

Comment: shell out and "grep" it.